# Disabling trigger in a linked server

Tags: t-sql, linked-server

I am trying to do a schema migration using PowerShell / TSQL but am having a few issues with using linked servers. Basically, the source DB backup is a higher version than that of the target SQL server so i am having to use linked servers to pull the data from the source database into a linked server database.

This is my first time using linked servers and one of the parts of the script i have is disabling certain triggers on the destination database to stop inserts from failing.

I figured out how to add columns using `EXEC` :

`EXEC('ALTER TABLE [TRS].dbo.AM ADD testColum INT') AT S1`

But the same process doesnt work for disabling triggers

`EXEC('DISABLE TRIGGER tr_SetFinalVersion ON [TRS].dbo.Contract;') AT S1`

Any idea how i would go about disabling these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables from your examples are different. Is it possible that you don't have permissions on the other table?

Also, you can try using ALTER TABLE to disable trigger.

```
EXEC('ALTER TABLE [TRS].[dbo].[Contract] DISABLE TRIGGER tr_SetFinalVersion') AT S1
```

[alter table trigger example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#b-disabling-and-re-enabling-a-trigger)